# How to encrypt ASAR archives?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, asar

Is there any possibility to encrypt an ASAR package so that possibly malicious actors cannot reverse-engineer my application in virtually no time? So far, I have not found any information on this whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

In short: no.

Javascript cannot be complied or protected. If your Electron Application is on another computer the source code (or at lest the parts that do not lie on a server) are open to the user.

Comment: the headers and body are encryptable but there are no guides out there on how to do it

Comment: I have never heard of an encrypted asar file beside some theoretical concepts. There is in fact a demo on github, but as the description is in japanese I cannot tell what it does or if it really works. https://github.com/toyobayashi/electron-asar-encrypt-demo

Comment: Thats in chinese btw. Thank got im chinese haha. If possible i might translate it to english. How did i not encounter this while searching

Comment: That could be useful for all. Maybe fork it if it works.